# Is there any alternative API for AirPrint api in iPad?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, printing

Is there any alternative API for AirPrint api in iPad?

My requirement is that i want to print from printer which does not support AirPrint.

and i do not want to install any third party app on my system in network which will pretend like AirPrinter for e.g. "AirPrint Hacktivator"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After bit of googling, I found 2 solutions

1) API - [e-Workshop](http://www.e-workshop-dev.com/PC_EN/develop_title_e.html)

2) Proxy Printer - [Printopia](http://www.ecamm.com/mac/printopia/) This software will pretend as AirPrinter to iPad/iPhone and you can print without buying AirPrinter. This will work with default printing API

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no alternative API for printing. In order to not have to ship gigabytes of printer drivers, Apple decided to only support a single printing protocol.

Comment: http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/printing-for-ipad/id397734760?mt=8 have look at this app, it allows print without air printer.. how this is posible?

Comment: @MitulNakum From the app description: "Ships with over 1400 Printer Drivers..." so they included all the drivers themselves.

Comment: this is the way... If I have to integrate with 2-3 printers then I can do like this. Am I right?

Comment: @MitulNakum sure looks that way.

Comment: and what do you think of this api/sdk?? e-workshop-dev.com/PC_EN/eprintsdk_e.html

Comment: Was it not a case of Apple being held up in court over a patent claim made by a third party? I could have sworn AirPrint was originally advertised to work with all printers.